# What are the differences between LaTeX plugins?

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-vim-latex

There are a number of Tex plugins for vim ([vim-latex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/), [AutomaticLatexPlugin](http://atp-vim.sourceforge.net/) to say a couple).

What are the differences in the provided functionalities between these (the ones I named and possibly others) TeX plugins?

---

Here is a couple of related questions on SO:

- [Latex and Vim usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3723493/4063051)
- [What are the necessary plugins in VIM for Latex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/541848/4063051)

Answer (score 41):

I will not provide an in-depth comparison, as I only have limited experience with the different plugins. I know a couple of plugins well ([LaTeX-Box](https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box/) and [LaTeX-Suite](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/)), and I know one plugin very well, since I am developing it myself: [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex). Thus, I will mostly write about vimtex. However, I will first point out some references that might be of interest to others.

## Some overview and references

There are *alot* of plugins for Vim. These are the ones I've recognized as being at least semi popular:

- [LaTeX-Suite](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net)
- [LaTeX-Box](https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box)
- [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex)
- [AutomaticTexPlugin](http://atp-vim.sourceforge.net)
- [vim-latex-live-preview](https://github.com/xuhdev/vim-latex-live-preview)

On [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com), there is a [huge list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) of LaTeX editors and IDEs. It gives a nice overview in general, but it also provides some overview of plugins for Vim:

- [Vim with LaTeX-Box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148473)
- [Vim with LaTeX-Suite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394)
- [Vim with Snipmate and rubber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5370)
- [Vim with vimtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252555)

## vimtex

vimtex is based on LaTeX-Box. It started out after I had contributed bug fixes and updates to LaTeX-Box for some time. I realized that the plugin could be written in a much more modern way if I wrote it from scratch. I first stripped most features and built a more robust and modular "engine". I then added features, and I think today it has most of the features of LaTeX-Box and then some.

Instead of giving a full list of features (see [instead here for that](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex#features)), I will rather try to point out some of the differences between vimtex and other plugins. However, I want to provide some bold claims:

- vimtex is the *most modern* Vim plugin for LaTeX available today
- The code is *high quality* and it is currently being [actively maintained](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues) by myself
- The plugin is mostly stable, even though some features are still being developed (and as such may be subject to change and updates)

### vimtex vs LaTeX-Box

Since vimtex is based on LaTeX-Box, it obviously has similar principles. The idea is to keep things simple and to solve problems thare are not already solved by other, better plugins. It utilizes [latexmk](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/) to compile the LaTeX documents, and it builds upon the internal Vim plugin for syntax highlighting.

There is currently one important feature in LaTeX-Box that is missing in vimtex: Single-shot compilation *with callback*. The reason that this feature is not in vimtex is simply because it is complicated, and that I never found a way to implement it that is simple enough for my own preference (suggestions are welcome, please don't hesitate to open issues or pull requests).

### vimtex vs LaTeX-Suite

The main difference between vimtex and LaTeX-Suite is probably that vimtex does not try to implement a full fledged IDE for LaTeX inside Vim. E.g.:

- vimtex does not provide a full snippet feature, because this is better handled by [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) or [neosnippet](https://github.com/Shougo/neosnippet.vim) or similar snippet engines.
- vimtex builds upon Vim principles: It provides text objects for environments, inline math, it provides motions for sections and paragraphs
- vimtex uses `latexmk` for compilation with a callback feature to get instant feedback on compilation errors
- vimtex is very modular: if you don't like a feature, you can turn it off.

Comment: Just want to make it clear: `vimtex` can work side-by-side with `Latex-Suite`, which means you can get the best of the two plugins *at the same time*. :)

Comment: How does vimtex compare to something like using coc together with coc-texlab? Can you use both of them together?

Comment: I don't know, as I've not used texlab yet. But I think it should work well together. You could use texlab with coc.nvim or other LSP-implementations for e.g. completion, which might work better than vimtex completion. But I would say vimtex completion is quite good, and so it should not be _much_ better. vimtex does provide a lot of other features as well, though, which would be orthogonal to the LSP.

Comment: For more information, see [this issue comment](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/1371#issuecomment-504428415) on the vimtex repo.

Answer (score 13):

I can't do comparison, as Vim-LaTeX is the only LaTeX plugin I've used. I have been using Vim-LaTeX for almost a year.
So I will talk about Vim-LaTeX alone.

There are *many* features present in Vim-LaTeX. I don't remember all of them. I'll just talk about features that I know and use constantly.

Note: These are *my limited user experience*, which may be *very misleading*. I'm not a seasoned Vim user. And I know of nothing about vimscript.

## IMAP() and `<C-j>` Jumpping

`IMAP()` function and `<C-j>` jumpping functions are provided separately as a plugin `imaps.vim` in Vim-LaTeX bundle. They are powerful features and could be very useful even when you are not writing LaTeX.

- `IMAP()` function provides a more natural way to do insert mode mappings and templating in general than the built-in `imap` and `iabbrev`, IMO.
- `<C-j>` jumpping is utilized by many Vim-LaTeX completion features. A jumpping point is indicated by `<++>`.
- Built-in insert mode key mappings are implemented as `IMAP()` calls. For example, you can find a long list of useful `IMAP()` calls in `main.vim` file:

  ```
  call IMAP ('__', '_{<++>}<++>', "tex")
  call IMAP ('()', '(<++>)<++>', "tex")
  call IMAP ('[]', '[<++>]<++>', "tex")
  call IMAP ('{}', '{<++>}<++>', "tex")
  ...
  call IMAP ('((', '\left( <++> \right)<++>', "tex")
  call IMAP ('[[', '\left[ <++> \right]<++>', "tex")
  call IMAP ('{{', '\left\{ <++> \right\}<++>', "tex")
  ...
  ```

Then when you type say `()`, the cursor will reside automatically between the parenthese, replacing the first `<++>`. After you finished typing inside, you kick `<C-j>` and bang, the cursor will move out of parenthese and you just keep typing forward. Once you are used to it, it begins to form a typing flow which is kinda addictive...

You see from above a `\left` `\right` pair can be typed easily with double stroke of its opening bracket. And `<C-j>` jumpping makes typing flow.

One major glitch of `IMAP()` and `<C-j>` thing is that *they messes up your last change history*. (One bug I wish to fix for a long time.) Therefore, you may encounter unexpected behavior when trying to redo your last change by `.` if your "supposed last change" contains these function calls.

- You can do all kinds of mappings using `IMAP()`, from simple key mappings to more complex templating. Here are some examples of my mappings (`ftplugin/tex.vim`):

  ```
  call IMAP('*EEQ',"\\begin{equation*}\<CR><++>\<CR>\\end{equation*}<++>",'tex')
  call IMAP('DEF',"\\begin{definition}[<++>]\<CR><++>\<CR>\\end{definition}<++>",'tex')
  call IMAP('BIC','\binom{<++>}{<++>}<++>','tex')
  call IMAP('PVERB','\PVerb{<++>}<++>','tex')
  call IMAP('VERB','\verb|<++>|<++>','tex')
  ```
- An interesting fact about `imaps.vim` plugin is that it's a global plugin, which implies its potential usage beyond LaTeX. Indeed, I do use `<++>` and `<C-j>` jumppings (combining with other plugins) to build code snippet templates in C.

## `<F5> <F7>` Insertion of Commands and Environments

One disadvantage of `IMAP()` is that the key combination can not be used in normal text anymore (unless you undo the mapping by `u`). In the cases that you just want to *trigger* the mapping as you wish, the `<F5>` and `<F7>` come in handy. These two keys are used for *triggering* environments and inline commands insertion, respectively. And they behave differently based on the mode and customizations from user.

- In Insert/Normal Mode, when the cursor is attaching a word or is in the word, pressing `<F5>` will by default insert a basic environment of the form

  ```
  \begin{word}
  <Cursor>
  \end{word}<++>
  ```

  based on the word; pressing `<F7>` will by default insert a basic inline command of the form `\word{}<++>` based on the word.
- "By default", I mean you can customize the behavior of a specific word when triggered by `<F5>`/`<F7>`. Here are some of my settings (`.vimrc`):

  ```
  let g:Tex_Com_newcommand = "\\newcommand{<++>}[<++>]{<++>}<++>"
  let g:Tex_Com_latex = "{\\LaTeX}<++>"
  let g:Tex_Com_D = "\\D{<++>}{<++>}<++>"
  ```
- In Insert/Normal Mode, when the cursor is *not* attached to anything (a.k.a *alone*), pressing `<F5>`/`<F7>` will prompt to you a menu to select environment/command to insert. Or you can type the name of desired environment/command at the bottom. Personally, I rarely use `<F5>`/`<F7>` this way.
- Press `<F5>`/`<F7>` after visually selecting a piece of text will prompt a menu for *wrapping text*. Then the selected text will be wrapped in the environment/command you selected or typed.
- In Insert/Normal Mode, when the cursor is in the scope of an environment/command, press `<Shift>+<F5>/<F7>` will prompt a menu for *changing environment/command*.

## Misc Key Mappings

- Greek Letters. `` `a `` to `` `z `` and corresponding capitals.
- Symbols like `` `8 `` for `\infty`, `` `< `` for `\le`, `` `I `` for `\int_{<++>}^{<++>}<++>`, etc.
- Pressing `"` twice gets a pair of TeX double quotes. So to type literal `"` character, you have to use .
- Pressing  in several enumeration environments will insert appropriate `\item` tag.
- You can wrap visually selected part of math in `\left` `\right` pair by `` `( ``, `` `[ `` and `` `{ ``.
- Folding is customizable. Three global variable control what can be folded: `Tex_FoldedSections`, `Tex_FoldedMisc`, and `Tex_FoldedEnvironments`.

Sometimes the built-in mappings have just gone too far or are not quit what you want. You can override the built-in mappings by redefining them in `after/ftplugin/tex.vim`:

```
call IMAP('`|','\abs{<++>}<++>','tex')
call IMAP('ETE',"\\begin{table}\<CR>\\centering\<CR>\\caption{<+Caption text+>}\<CR>\\label{tab:<+label+>}\<CR>\\begin{tabular}{<+dimensions+>}\<CR><++>\<CR>\\end{tabular}\<CR>\\end{table}<++>",'tex')
call IMAP('==','==','tex')
call IMAP('`\','`\','tex')
```

## Set Multiple Compilation Engine

I always need to switch between `pdflatex` and `xelatex` engine. Thus, I have the following lines in my `.vimrc`:

```
"switch to pdflatex
function SetpdfLaTeX()
    let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex --interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -src-specials $*'
endfunction
noremap <Leader>lp :<C-U>call SetpdfLaTeX()<CR>

"switch to xelatex
function SetXeLaTeX()
    let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'xelatex --interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -src-specials $*'
endfunction
noremap <Leader>lx :<C-U>call SetXeLaTeX()<CR>
```

## View PDF, Forward and Backward Search between Vim and PDF viewer

This is a messy and complicated topic. With certain PDF viewer and *a certain amount of luck*, it can be very easy. But it's mainly a matter of google search.

## Suggestions

- You should find your balance between LaTeX way and Vim-LaTeX way.
- Vim-LaTeX is no light-weight at all. There are some features and/or key mappings you'll possibly never gonna use and you have to manually override them.
- You use Vim. You know what *patience* mean. :-)

Overall, I think it will work well if you are willing to invest some time to tame the beast. That being said, had I time and adequate knowledge, I will surely thin off the overhead features and explore the potentials of integration with other plugins.

## References

- [Official user manual](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=manual&title=Manual#user-manual)
- [Cheat sheet](http://michaelgoerz.net/refcards/vimlatexqrc.pdf)