# Suppressing standard output during compilation in vim-latex

Tags: plugin-vim-latex

I'm just starting to learn Vim-LaTeX, and there are a couple things that bug me. First, I would like to suppress all standard output to the command line when I compile using `\ll`, but I would still like errors to show up in the quick-fix window. Also, Vim prompts me to press Enter after compilation with `\ll` and after viewing with `\lv`, both of which I would like to skip and always go immediately back to Vim as soon as compilation is done or the pdf is opened. I can suppress all output using a line like this in my .vimrc:

```
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode $* >/dev/null'
```

but then if there's an error it doens't tell me. Any thoughts or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I use vim-latex (gvim) on windows 10 and it doesn't prompt me to press enter after compilation with `\ll` or viewing with `\lv`, if you mean that you have to press enter after the compilation is finished to go back on writing. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but i want to pitch in that there are alternatives to LaTeX-Suite, e.g. LatexBox and vimtex. I'm the developer of vimtex, and in my humble opinion, it is a much more modern approach to a LaTeX plugin for vim.

Comment: Yes, after `\ll` or `\lv` I see `Press ENTER or type command to continue` in my command prompt. I have to press enter to get out of the command line and back into vim. I'm using Vim 7.3 in OSX El Capitan. When you compile with `\ll` does the long-winded output of the compiler show up in your command line? That's the main thing I want to get rid of , but the pressing enter thing would be nice too.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg it would be nice to have vimtex compared to the other available plugins by someone like you who knows them best. Did you see [this question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2047/602)?

Comment: @glS Thanks, I didn't see that one. I just added some information [about vimtex](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5747/21). I hope it is useful.

Comment: @BenLindsay maybe it happens with vim and not with gvim. Did you try remapping `\ll` to something like `\ll<CR>`? I don't know about suppressing the output sorry, I never saw it as a problem myself.

Comment: @glS That mapping isn't working for me, but I've decided to live with pressing enter. I just started pressing enter during compilation, so there's no extra time delay. I still would like to have the compilation output go somewhere else besides my current terminal session though.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg I might start looking into other plugins like yours or LaTex-Box. Does your package (or any other package that you know of) provide a way to direct the compilation output to somewhere other than my current terminal session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to both my problems was, as [Karl Yngve Lervåg](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/21/karl-yngve-lerv%C3%A5g) suggested, to ditch Vim-LaTeX in favor of a better plugin. I'm currently trying out LaTeX-Box, which solves both of my problems nicely. Maybe I'll try out vimtex next to see which one I like better.