# Am I missing something using vim-LaTeX?

Tags: plugin-vim-latex

I am an average user of vim and LaTeX. I hate using anything but the keyboard while working on the computer. Following popular recommendations I have been using vim-LaTeX for few years now and have not used anything else. I love it. But sometimes when I am writing something (heavy technical writing) then few things seem difficult such as tables. I know tables are not the most intuitive part of LaTeX, but I was wondering if I am missing anything using vim-LaTeX. Are there any better options that you can suggest? Kindly also mention (if possible) what are advantages and disadvantages of switching. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is closely related to [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/what-are-the-differences-between-latex-plugins), which has some potential useful answers, for instance [my answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5747/21) about [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex).

Comment: Thanks Karl. It was helpful and now I know about one more possible plug in I can try. May be I have compare their features to arrive at the answer I am looking for.