# How to discover available keybindings for Vim's vanilla TeX mode?

Tags: key-bindings, filetype-tex

I'd like to use Vim (version 7.4) to edit TeX files using the built-in, vanilla TeX mode. How do I find out about any available keybindings that are special for this mode? Does not seem to be listed in the `:help`.

Answer (score 2):

There are none. The vanilla TeX mode (ftplugin and syntax plugin) defines syntax highlighting and sets some options. That's it. If you want any additional features, you have to create them yourself or use one of many plugins. See e.g. [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/what-are-the-differences-between-latex-plugins) for some information about different plugins.

Comment: With a perfectly valid, **great** answer like this, there's no reason why this question should deserve a negative vote number; even if it *is* from someone who doesn't know the answer or the reason for the question.